# Magento1.9 : Adding multi domain in multi website

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency, multidomain, multi-website

We have added multiple websites in different  domains  but it does not redirect the website, all required setting are  enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You may have skipped or missed a step.

Please check below steps:

- Create root categories for different websites. (Not mandatory, but recommended)
- Create multiple websites, their respective stores, and store views.
- Create folders for newly created websites, copy index.php and .htaccess files into these folders and make necessary changes in index.php or .htaccess files.
- Make changes in secure and unsecure **Base URLs** of different websites from **System > Configuration > General (Web)** section. Do remember to select a particular website to set Base URL.

Please let me know if you are able to fix the issue.

Comment: yes i have already fixed

Comment: If my solution worked for you, please upvote. If not, please share the way, you fixed the problem, so that others can also get the benefit.

Comment: ok Magneto Multi store Setup
first we website created on System->Manage Stores
create a website, store and store view. Make a note of the codes as you need those in the code below in that

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

     case 'first-store.com':
     case 'www.example1.com':
        Mage::run('website_code1', 'website');
     break;

     case 'example2.com':
     case 'www.second-store.com':
        Mage::run('website_code1'', 'website');
     break;
 default: 
        Mage::run();
     break;
      }

Comment: Please post your solution as answer for better readability and ease of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very brief guide:

First create the website,store. This is all done via the Magento administration.

System->Manage Stores

for each store that you want, create a website, store and store view. Make a note of the codes as you need those in the code below.

Then in your index.php file have some code like this:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

     case 'example1.com':
     case 'www.example1.com':
        Mage::run('website_code1', 'website');
     break;

     case 'example2.com':
     case 'www.example2.com':
        Mage::run('website_code2', 'website');
     break;


     default: //run the default store if for some reason the above hasn't worked.
        Mage::run();
     break;
}
```